# Unable to create an Executable JAR on Eclipse. Couldn't find main

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I've seen many other answers to similar questions, however, none of the solutions I've seen will do the trick, I've tried them all but I keep getting the same error message:

> "JAR creation failed. [...] Could not find main method from given
>   launch configuration."

It might have something to do with my Java app using external images with Swing, since I got some problems while trying to create the JAR before getting to the final step.
The main method is there, it works if I run it from there and it has the right format, parameters etc. just in case you're wondering.
I'd appreciate some help, since it would be really useful for me to keep track of finished releases of my software. It's a Java application with no external libraries, just some images and that's it. I don't really need anything fancy, just a runnable package that I can send to some people to test for errors.

Comment: Some time eclipse is crazy. Let's create a new launch configuration, choose your main method, then run this launch configuration to check if it correct. => export Jar by choosing the new launch configuration just created

Comment: I have tried that a thousand times and it seems to work fine when I run it, but not when I export the Runnable JAR :/

Comment: Try to delete all old launch configuration, restart eclipse and then create a new one

Comment: I've tried that and nothing seems to work, I don't know what's wrong, but the solution underneath seems to do the trick! Thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: Hi - I deleted the old configuration file; and re-created it.  But still get the same error - "JAR export finished with warnings. 
    Could not find main method from given launch configuration."  Also, in Run Configurations menu, the entries shown in the Search list does not shot the class containing the main( ) method - can that be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for what I understand, you just need something that will run, not necessarily a "Runnable JAR" as Eclipse calls it, and what I assume you're trying to do.
I ran into this very same issue some time ago, and although I'm not sure it is the optimal solution, I'd say it will meet your requirements and it worked perfectly for me.

First off, as you probably have done before, right click on the project folder, then click Export.

Here is where we make things differently, instead of "Runnable JAR File", just select "JAR File".
The menu here is a little bit different from that on the Runnable JAR screen. Just select the resouces you'd like to export, then the JAR file destination and click next. Adjust the settings there and when you get to the final screen, select the application entry point (in this case, your Main class).
Click finish and that should work this time.

I don't really know what causes this behaviour or why it works this way, but for me, it just did every time I couldn't manage to do it using the "Runnable JAR" option.
To run the JAR package, it should be as easy as going to the console on any computer with Java installed and type:

```
java -jar [pathToYourFileHere]
```

Good luck and let me know if it works. Hope it is what you needed!

Comment: This might be what I need as long as someone can run it from another PC just having that file! I'll try it now

Comment: Yes, anyone with the JAR file will be able to run it with that command. No Eclipse or anything needed, just Java installed and the Command Prompt in Windows and Terminal in Mac.